# Hard drive flagged to unallocated and i cannot boot or format the hdd

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I had Windows 10 and I wanted to install Ubuntu beside my Win10, so I installed Ubuntu with root and home and swap but I chose to boot from root so that I could add it in Windows10 boot menu with EasyBSD and just like [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iSAyiicyQY) but in the software after installing Linux it didn't let me add the Linux boot.

So I left it and shutdown my laptop. After that I started my laptop few hours later after the Asus logo this error came

> Reboot and select proper boot device
> or insert boot media in selected boot device and Press a key

Then I tried to fix boot with Ubuntu live and Windows 10 but  both ways I face the fact that I have no OS on my laptop and my whole HDD is shown unallocated like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvduP.jpg).

I have [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqyt9.jpg) BIOS options. I upgraded BIOS to version 304 on ASUS n552vw successfully but nothing changed and still my whole HDD is unallocated. I have put my HDD on another laptop and still unallocated but could run recovery with disk drill and saved my data. When I put my HDD as external in other laptop In diskmgmt.msc I can not start the drive and in diskpart it does not show anything.

I bought a Samsung SSD 250GB evo860 and put it instead of my default HDD but it even does not go to BIOS setting and freezes at ASUS logo screen. I guess ASUS made its HDD somehow that no one can use it without the default HDD.

I have seen many people with same condition without getting answer and due to that I cannot start my laptop and  without the default HDD the laptop will be useless.

Comment: Be very careful but the drive is probably OK. What is most likely happening is that the partition table is not recognized. Have you changed UEFI settings? If the new partition table is not recognize by Windows, you may have to overwrite it back to the type is was before but that could mean reinstalling Linux.

Comment: Thanks @Itai for your answer. I did not changed UEFI settings but it was in my boot settings before and now its not there anymore. About reinstalling linux ,i tried to; but the problem is that i can not reinstall it since the whole disk is shown unallocated. Do you have any decision on that and how to show my volumes On the disk and flags?

Comment: @Itai i remembered that i did not mess with UEFI settings and i can boot usb drive in UEFI now.